# XML::Simple doesn't seem to work with a URL. Is this correct?

Tags: xml, perl, xml-simple

I am using the following script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -wT

use strict;
use warnings;

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "xml reader";

# use module
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

#print Dumper (XML::Simple->new()->XMLin());
```

and it will read in my xml file called xml.xml

If I now move the xml file out of my cgi-bin, change its name and reference it using:

```
#print Dumper (XML::Simple->new()->XMLin("../resource.xml"));
```

It still works.

If I now try and use a url instead the script doesn't return anything:

```
print Dumper (XML::Simple->new()->XMLin("http://digitalessence.net/resource.xml"));
```

I have tried with and without the http://, without the www and all sorts of different ways of doing this but it doesn't return anything.

Have I done something silly here or will it just not load a remote url?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `XMLin()` method in `XML::Simple` does not support fetching the XML from an URL. You would need to fetch the XML separately, either to a file or directly into a Perl scalar variable, before applying `XMLin()`. This is clear from the `XML::Simple` documentation.

Comment: Ah, have just spotted this in the doc:

"Names in XML must begin with a letter. The remaining characters may be letters, digits, hyphens (-), underscores (_) or full stops (.). It is also allowable to include one colon (:) in an element name but this should only be used when working with namespaces (XML::Simple can only usefully work with namespaces when teamed with a SAX Parser). But couldn't see it say that I couldn't use an url in 36pt red font so I missed it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Hedley, the text you quote talks about the input to `XMLout()`. I was referring to the documentaiton of `XMLin()` (which is what you're trying to use): "The XML specifier can be one of the following: A filename [...], undef [...], A string of XML [...], An IO::Handle object [...]." No mentioning of URL in there.

Answer (score 5):

You can modify your program as follows, using LWP to retrieve the remote resource:

```
[...]
# use module
use XML::Simple;
use LWP;
use Data::Dumper;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $req = HTTP::Request->new( GET => "http://digitalessence.net/resource.xml" );
my $res = $ua->request( $req );

print Dumper (XML::Simple->new()->XMLin( $res->content ));
```